# Freemarker: Unexpected directive, "</#if>"

Tags: java, freemarker

I've got some code in my login template that shows error on wrong credentials written in freemarker. Everything looks just how it should, syntax is correct, but sparkjava throws ParseException

```
freemarker.core.ParseException: Syntax error in template "freemarker/admin_login.ftl" in line 40, column 9:
Unexpected directive, "</#if>". Check if you have a valid #if-#elseif-#else structure.
at freemarker.core.FMParser.generateParseException(FMParser.java:5251)
at freemarker.core.FMParser.jj_consume_token(FMParser.java:5122)
at freemarker.core.FMParser.Root(FMParser.java:3433)
at freemarker.template.Template.<init>(Template.java:208)
at freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.loadTemplate(TemplateCache.java:495)
at freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.getTemplate(TemplateCache.java:409)
at freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.getTemplate(TemplateCache.java:261)
at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:1786)
at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:1646)
at spark.template.freemarker.FreeMarkerEngine.render(FreeMarkerEngine.java:69)
at pl.bluedotdevs.adminpanel.utils.ViewUtil.render(ViewUtil.java:22)
at pl.bluedotdevs.adminpanel.login.LoginController.lambda$static$0(LoginController.java:21)
at spark.RouteImpl$1.handle(RouteImpl.java:61)
at spark.http.matching.Routes.execute(Routes.java:61)
at spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter.doFilter(MatcherFilter.java:128)
at spark.embeddedserver.jetty.JettyHandler.doHandle(JettyHandler.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:189)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:302)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:245)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My code:

```
<#if($authenticationFailed)>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Niepoprawny email lub hasło</div>
    <#elseif($authenticationSucceeded)>
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Zalogowano pomyślnie</div>-->
    <#elseif($loggedOut)>
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Wylogowano pomyślnie</div>-->
    </#if>
```

I really don't know what is wrong. I have looked in documentation and I think my elseif syntax is good. Could you help me?

Comment: The expected pattern is `"#if" Whitespace+ Expression`, and you miss the whitespace. Why the misleading error message though? Because FreeMarker is configured there to be in fully 2.3.0 mode (`incompatible_improvements` configuration setting), so it emulates a sneaky parser glitch, where the `<#if(`, when it's the first FreeMarker tag in the template, is mistakenly treated as static text, and thus the problem will only surface at the `</#if>`. I highly recommend to raise `incompatible_improvements` to at least 2.3.19. Also, using `()` and `$` like that isn't right, but see accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parentheses in your conditionals are causing a parse error (e.g. `<#if($authenticationFailed)>`). Either remove them, or as @ddekany notes in the comment below put a space between the if keyword and the left parenthesis.

Also variables do not normally start with a `$`, but it will work if the name of the variable truly includes the `$` character.

Try this.

```
<#if $authenticationFailed>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Niepoprawny email lub hasło</div>
<#elseif $authenticationSucceeded>
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Zalogowano pomyślnie</div>-->
<#elseif $loggedOut>
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Wylogowano pomyślnie</div>-->
</#if>
```

Comment: In fact, it's totally legal to use `()` there (it's redundant, but it's just an expression after all), also variable names can start with `$` (though they will be treated as part of the name, which was obviously not the intent of the OP). The problem is that there's no space between `#if` and the `(`. Unfortunately the parser has some bug and it blames the `/#if`...

Comment: I have check why the error message is wrong... see my comment under OP-s question.

Comment: Ok. I'm happy to edit my answer further if required.

Comment: Go ahead... it turns out settings `incompatible_improvements` to a higher value gives a much better error message.

Answer (score 1):

The parenthesis probably while you are using with the `if` is causing the exception. Concrete examples of expressions used in Freemaker are -

> When you supply value for interpolations: The usage of interpolations
>   is *${expression}* where expression gives the value you want to insert
>   into the output as text. So *${(5 + 8)/2}* prints "6.5" to the output
>   (or possibly "6,5" if the language of your output is not US English).

So you could try using `<#if ${authenticationFailed}>` if that be the case.

> When you supply a value for the directive parameter: You have already
>   seen the if directive in the Getting Started section. The syntax of
>   this directive is: <#if expression>.... The expression here must
>   evaluate to a boolean value. For example in <#if 2 < 3> the 2 < 3 (2
>   is less than 3) is an expression which evaluates to true.

In which case you can simply use `<#if authenticationFailed>` as suggested by @Frank as well.

***Note*** - Same applies to all the conditional branches used in the code shared by you.

*Source* - [Freemaker docs template](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#)